# jquery-autocomplete default selection

Tags: selection, default, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to transfer a select with more than 20 000 items (clients info) to a auto-complete input field to make the form faster on loading.

Currently I'm using the Dyve autocomplete plugins (https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete.git)

The problem that I face is that I cannot set a default value of in the field as I did with the select.

My original code was:

```
...
<td>
    <a href="#" onClick="document.form1.blank_sel_numeroclient.value = '<?php echo("$row_rs_detail[numeroclient]");?>';">
        <img src="images/blocnote.png" width="20" height="15" alt="Modifier" />
    </a>
</td>
...
<td align="left" colspan="2">
    <select name="blank_sel_numeroclient" id="blank_sel_numeroclient" style="width:475px; text-align:left" >
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <?php
            do
            {
                echo("<option value=\"".$row_rs_clients['numeroclient']."\">".$row_rs_clients['numeroclient']."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row_rs_clients['nom']."</option>\n");
            } while ($row_rs_clients = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_clients));
            $rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_clients);
            if($rows > 0)
            {
                mysql_data_seek($rs_clients, 0);
                $row_rs_clients = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_clients);
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
...
```

Now the code that I try to use:
Main HTML

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css">
<script src="JavascriptFiles/jquery.autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<td>
    <!-- This is not working -->        
    <a href="#" onClick="document.form1.blank_sel_numeroclient.value            = '<?php echo($row_rs_clients['numeroclient']);?>';">
        <img src="images/blocnote.png" width="20" height="15" alt="Modifier" />
    </a>
</td>
...
<td align="left" colspan="2">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#blank_sel_numeroclient').autocomplete('cedule/liste-client-autocomplete.php',
                {
                    minChars: 1,
                    useCache: false,
                    selectFirst: true,
                    selectOnly: true,
                    sortResults: true
                });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="blank_sel_numeroclient" name="blank_sel_numeroclient" style="width:475px; text-align:left" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="blank_sel_numeroclienthidden" name="blank_sel_numeroclienthidden" />
</td>
...
```

Content of liste-client-autocomplete.php:

```
<?php
    // si on reçoit une donnée
    if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
        $q = htmlentities($_GET['q']); // protection

        // connexion à la base de données
        try {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=somehost;dbname=somedatabase', 'someusername', 'somepassword');
            $bdd->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            exit('Impossible de se connecter à la base de données.');
        }
        // écriture de la requête
        $requete = "SELECT CONCAT_WS('\t',numeroclient,nom) as nom FROM clients WHERE numeroclient LIKE '". $q ."%' ORDER BY LENGTH(numeroclient), numeroclient";
        // exécution de la requête
        $resultat = $bdd->query($requete) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
        // affichage des résultats
        while($donnees = $resultat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $donnees['nom'] ."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

So I want to have the "exact" same effect of the original code but with a lightweight autocomplete feature because with more than 20 000 items in the DB the page take for ever to load. (2.2MB just for the select value...)

So if somebody can told me a way to do this or a better one because I'm now stuck.

Best regards,
RiOt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally worked out something!

By replacing

```
...
<td>
    <!-- This is not working -->        
    <a href="#" onClick="document.form1.blank_sel_numeroclient.value            = '<?php echo($row_rs_clients['numeroclient']);?>';">
        <img src="images/blocnote.png" width="20" height="15" alt="Modifier" />
    </a>
</td>
...
```

with

```
...
<td>
    <!-- Seems to work -->        
    <a href="#" onClick="document.form1.blank_sel_numeroclient.value = '<?php echo($row_rs_detail['numeroclient']."\t".$row_rs_detail['cl_nom']);?>';">
        <img src="images/blocnote.png" width="20" height="15" alt="Modifier" />
    </a>
</td>
...
```

Seems to resolve the default selection issue.
It seems that you need to provide the full item in the autocomplete list including formatting to be able to "select it" trough script call.

So as my SQL request result for the list was : `CONCAT_WS('\t',numeroclient,nom)`

That for example will result as : "19078 [TAB CHAR] Mrs Smith"

I've got to provide the input field value node the same so :

```
echo($row_rs_detail['numeroclient']."\t".$row_rs_detail['cl_nom']);
```

Which will translate to the same : "19078 [TAB CHAR] Mrs Smith"

And then populate correctly the input field!

Don't know if it make sense but it worked for me!

Best regards and hope it could help someone else!

RiOt